# Show that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$ if $f:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ is nonnegative, integrable, and uniformly continuous.

Tags: analysis

I have several questions here.
First, does the fact that $f$ is integral means the integral is finite? I was wondering if I can prove that $L(f,P)$ goes to infinity for some partition $P$ if $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)\neq0$.
Secondly, I think I might need to use the definition of improper integrals here, but I'm not sure how the definition helps.

Comment: Yes, saying that $f$ is integrable means that its integral is finite.

Comment: If you're talking about Riemann integration, then yes, you'll need an improper integral to accommodate the domain $[0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

*First: yes, saying that $f$ is integrable means that its improper Riemann integral over $[0, \infty)$ is finite.*

Then, use a proof by contradiction and Cauchy criterion for improper integral convergence.

If $f$ doesn’t converge to zero, it exists $a\gt 0$ and a sequence $\{x_n\}$ converging to $\infty$ such that $f(x_n) \ge a$ and $x_{n+1}-x_n \ge 2$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$.

If $\int_0^\infty f(x) \ dx$ exists, then
(using Cauchy criterion for improper integral convergence) $$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int_{x_n-1}^{x_n+1} f(x) \ dx =0.$$

Derive a contradiction with the fact that $f$ is supposed to be uniformly continuous.

Comment: Is the hypothesis of nonnegativeness necessary ? Is it possible to prove the theorem without that hypothesis ?

Comment: @Angelo You're right. The nonnegativeness hypothesis can be dropped.

Comment: Could you modify your proof in order that it works even without the nonnegativeness hypothesis ?

Comment: @Angelo It is immediate. As if $f$ doesn't converge to zero, either $f$ or $-f$ satisfies all the steps of the proof.

Comment: I'm not sure how the why we need $x_{n+1}-x_n \geq 2$ here. My takeaway from your hint is that if $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)\neq 0$, then there exists some $x_n\to \infty$ with $x_n\geq a$. Since f is uniformly continuous, for $a/2$, there is some $\delta$ such that $f(x)\geq a/2$ for all $x$ with $x-x_n < \delta$. Thus we have $\int_{x_n+\delta}^{x_n-\delta} f(x) \ dx \geq a/\delta$, which is a contradiction of the Cauchy criterion. But I'm not sure if my understanding is right.